# Match string only if a word in the string does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, regex, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to extract table names from a SQL script. I have the following string:

```
from db1.tableX tbx1 --quantity table
inner join tableY tbx2  on tbx1.xyz=tbx2.xyz
```

I don't want to match this string because `tabley` is not prefixed with a database name. The way I am trying to do this is by detecting the word "on" in the string before the database name.

My regex is matching `tablex` but also matches `tbx1`, which I dont want my expression to match.

I would like it to match only in this situation.

```
from db1.tableX tbx1 --quantity table
inner join db1.tableY tbx2 on tbx1.xyz = tbx2.xyz
```

My regex should give me `tableX` and `tableY` because they are prefixed by a database name.

Here is my expression:

```
(insert\s+into|from|inner\s+join|left\s+outer\s+join|join)\s+[\sa-zA-Z0-9_$#-]*\.\s*(?<table>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?=\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_$#-]+)*
```

Comment: the difference between the two situations is unclear to me. The only difference is in the database name (db1 instead of dbo). Also you say you try detecting the word "on"; I don't see it in your regex.

Comment: my post was edited by abatishchev. the difference between the two is in the first situation and other one is that in the first, the tableY is not prefixed by a databasename (i am not sure why the admin edited that post) and in the second situation, the tables are prefixed by a databasename. In the first situation, i dont want to match tableY because it is not prefixed by a databasename.

Comment: If you have a database name then the correct syntax for SQL-Server would be `database.owner.table` or `database..table`, i.e.: `db1.dbo.table` or `db1..table`.

Comment: tableY in this case is a volatile table in teradata. it does not need to be prefixed and i don't want a match for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your expression

```
(?<=\b(from|join)\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_$#-]*\.\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

It will yield the table name directly, without having to use named groups. I am using the pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find
```

This returns only the part "find" as match value. As prefix I use "from" or "join" followed by the database name the dot and possibly spaces.

`\b` is the beginning or end of a word.

The last part `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` is the table name.

It makes no difference whether you have an inner join, outer join etc., so I dropped this distinction.

Comments are ugly to detect, beacuse they can contain about anything and can appear about everywhere. Also you have two types of comments `-- Until end of line` and `\* ... *\`.

You could try to detect comments and spaces like this

```
(\s|--.*?$|\\\*.*?\*\\)+
```

Note that the backspace and the star have to be escaped, so `\*` becomes `\\\*` and `*\` becomes `\*\\`.

`$` denotes the end of line. The `?` after `.*` ensures that not several comments are skipped at once, thus skipping meaningful text between them.

This will work in most cases; however, comment like structures could be included within string literals: `SELECT 'hello -- world' AS greeting FROM ...`. This is not a comment! Without a full syntax analysis of the SQL text you will not be able to cover all possible cases. But you cannot do this with Regex. Regex has its limits.

Comment: Oliver, your solution seems to be working fine. can you quickly explain  me what is happening?

Comment: oliver, it nearly worked. the one place it is not working is when i have comments added after that inner join statement 
so for example..... from db1.tableX tbx1 --quantity table inner join -- inventory table db1.tableY tbx2 on tbx1.xyz = tbx2.xyz
I had put a \s in the character class

Comment: thanks Oliver for your help. I understand the limits of regex. I have seen on other posts suggesting to use a SQL parser. However, it is a paid application and at this point, that is out of question. I am not trying to build anything fancy and I am just trying to explore some stuff here. Your help has been invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

*Step by step:*

1) http://regexr.com?33tto

I don't know why you've put that lookahead at the end of the match. I don't think you need it, so I removed it.

2) http://regexr.com?33ttr

Now we get to the problem that you've indicated. The problem is that in your database name matching `[\sa-zA-Z0-9_$#-]*` you've included whitespace as a valid char. I've removed that too.

3) http://regexr.com?33ttu

Is this the desired outcome?

Comment: the reason i put the \s is i could have a situation where there would be a comment put in the script after the inner join statement.. so for example.
from db1.tableX tbx1 --quantity table
inner join -- inventory table db1.tableY tbx2 on tbx1.xyz = tbx2.xyz

Comment: this will not be possible with a single regex, unless you can 'predict' where the comments are going to be. Can you? If not, you would have to chain the matches and filterings of multiple regexes.

Comment: agreed with your statement